# model.fit() results in 'TypeError: 'module' object is not callable'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am experiencing a TypeError anytime I am trying to train my model with tensorflow. So far:

```
history = model.fit(train_batches,
                    steps_per_epoch=train_steps,
                    class_weight=class_weights,
                    validation_data=validation_batches,
                    validation_steps=val_steps,
                    epochs=30,
                    verbose=1,
                    callbacks=callbacks_list
                    )
```

gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/brian/Desktop/381-deep-learning/main.py", line 359, in <module>
    callbacks=callbacks_list
  File "/home/brian/Desktop/381-deep-learning/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 66, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/brian/Desktop/381-deep-learning/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 815, in fit
    model=self)
  File "/home/brian/Desktop/381-deep-learning/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 1112, in __init__
    model=model)
  File "/home/brian/Desktop/381-deep-learning/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 772, in __init__
    peek, x = self._peek_and_restore(x)
  File "/home/brian/Desktop/381-deep-learning/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 830, in _peek_and_restore
    peek = next(x)
  File "/home/brian/Desktop/381-deep-learning/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py", line 104, in __next__
    return self.next(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/brian/Desktop/381-deep-learning/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py", line 116, in next
    return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)
  File "/home/brian/Desktop/381-deep-learning/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py", line 239, in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples
    x = self.image_data_generator.standardize(x)
  File "/home/brian/Desktop/381-deep-learning/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/image_data_generator.py", line 704, in standardize
    x = self.preprocessing_function(x)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Here is my model definition:

```
resnet = tf.keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2.InceptionResNetV2()
predictions_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(7, activation='softmax')(x)

# Create an Image Data Generator to input later into our model.
data_generation = ImageDataGenerator(
    # Use Inception ResNet v2
    preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2
)


model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=resnet.input, outputs=predictions_layer)
```

Everything up to this point had been working fine, and I double checked all my import statements (which this error usually arises from), and all seems to be in check:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import shutil
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau, ModelCheckpoint


from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from PIL import ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
```

Some things I have tried so far are downgrading the versions of Tensorflow (2.2.0 -> 1.15.2) and Keras (2.3.1 -> 1.2.2); the only difference I get when doing this is my model makes it to the first epoch, but then fails with the same error.

Also, if it makes a difference here's the method I used to compile my model:

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.0007), loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.categorical_accuracy])
```

As well as the problematic callbacks_list in question (however after using Pycharm debugger, the value of this list is as expected):

```
checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='categorical_accuracy', verbose=1,
                             save_best_only=True, mode='max')

reduce_lr = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='categorical_accuracy', factor=0.5, patience=2,
                                   verbose=1, mode='max', min_lr=0.00001)

callbacks_list = [checkpoint, reduce_lr]
```

I have also provided a pastebin of the entire file in case there is anything important I missed out on which can contribute to the problem: https://pastebin.com/raw/XCWj0b78

Comment: You need to pass both a features and a targets array to `.fit()` instead of just a single array. That is definitely an issue, not sure if it is _the_ issue in this case.

Comment: Please eidt your question to include your model definition.

Comment: @desertnaut done. would you like me to also put my training/testing batches?

Comment: The problem is here: preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2, you are passing a module, not a function

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Solved! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling a module instead of the class that is contained in the module.

```
# Create an Image Data Generator to input later into our model.
data_generation = ImageDataGenerator(
    # Use Inception ResNet v2
    preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2.preprocess_input
)
```

Reading the docs led me to use the .preprocess_input() function in my generator.